# how to trim whitespace in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

here is a link to a GS that has fields that have whitespace. i want to use the native GS 'trim whitespace' feature but it isnt detecting any whitespace. can you suggest an alternate solution.

note* id like to know if there id an extension or native GS way to do this, not convert to microsoft or manually write and trigger a script.

thanks community members.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NcAvTVwD9nSZtN59LzyuSvbpcDiYUhW8dkhgTcbt0mo/edit?usp=sharing

so far i have not found any extension and the native GS trim whitespace feature isnt intelligent enogh to see the spaces before or after in cells A2-A15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=arrayformula(trim(substitute(A2:A29,char(160),char(32))))
```

Comment: I beg of you (and player0) to not use INDEX() instead of ARRYFORMULA() for no reason.  It just confuses future readers of the formulas! :)

Comment: changed it:) will try n' rem'er for future...